# Salesforce Email sending with attachment adds extra extension .html

Tags: salesforce, sendmail

I am sending email with 3 attachment it's work fine but when attachment files size are large then it adds extra extension with file name i.e test.pdf comes along with (test.pdf.html) in my email and mail goes to SPAM folder.
below is my code.

```
    if(strAttachFile != null && strAttachFile != '' && fileBody != null) {
        Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa1 = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();  
        efa1.setFileName(objAttachment1.Name);        
        efa1.setbody(objAttachment1.Body); 
        fileAttachments.add(efa1);
    }
    if(strAttachFile1 != null && strAttachFile1 != ''  && fileBody1 != null) {
        Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa2 = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();  
        efa2.setFileName(objAttachment2.Name);
        efa2.setbody(objAttachment2.Body); 
        fileAttachments.add(efa2);
        system.debug('---fileAttachments---'+fileAttachments);
    }
    if(strAttachFile2 != null && strAttachFile2 != '' && fileBody2  != null) {
        Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa3 = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();  
        efa3.setFileName(objAttachment3.Name);
        efa3.setbody(objAttachment3.Body); 
        fileAttachments.add(efa3);
    }

    mail.setFileAttachments(fileAttachments); 
    system.debug('---mail---'+mail);
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the way Salesforce sends attachments, probably related to the size of the attachment.

Salesforce automatically converts attachments over 3mb and sends them as links.

The HTML file links to a server hosted by salesforce and store this file for 30 days.(as a solotion The email must not be sent through the Force.com servers.)

That is all.

Comment: 1) Is there a way to disable this setting?  2) How would I send an email from Salesforce bypassing Force.com servers - via a webservice instead of via Messaging.sendEmail()?